# Erro de versão do Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver esse erro no Android Studio?

Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE variable to...

[image: Erro Gradle]

erro-gradle.PNG1055x71 6.59 KB

Meu classpath esta assim:

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'

Nesse link diz que a ultima versão do gradle é a alpha4 mas não funciona como alpha4.

Link: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

Já cliquei no link do erro mas não funciona também.

Como solucionar esse problema?

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode alterar o `classpath` e colocar um "+" antes da versão que define a alteração, assim, ele não perderá a compatibilidade (tão cedo).

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.+'
```

Fazendo isso você garante que será suportado até enquanto houver versões 2.2.qualquer versão

Quanto mais especifico for, maior a chance de perder a compatibilidade, quanto maior for a granularidade, maior a chance de manter a compatibilidade e ter que refazer algo que a API mudou.

Por exemplo:
Você pode fazer isso:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.+'
```

Mas é arriscado, porque o desenvolvedor pode deprecar algum método a partir da 2.3 e você ser pego de surpresa e ter que refazer algumas coisas a "toque de caixa".

Comment: Carlos vlw pela resposta.
Editei aqui mas não funcionou.

Obrigado cara.

Comment: Patz, tentou dar um Fix Plugin?

Comment: Sim mano mas mesmo assim não deu certo.